# How to create class in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

i have problem in create class

i have 1 class called "lib" :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for lib
/// </summary>
public class lib
{
    public static SqlConnection con;
    public static void constr()
    {
        lib.con = new SqlConnection();
        lib.con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=FroumDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123";
    }

    //insert
    public static SqlCommand cmd;
    public static void insert(string TableName ,string FieldNames, string values)
    {
        lib.constr();
        lib.cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into " + TableName + " (" + FieldNames + ") values(" + values + ")", lib.con);
        lib.cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        lib.con.Open();
        lib.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lib.con.Close();
    }
}
```

and in webform i used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class ForumPost : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        string t = "TPost";
        string f = "PostTitle,PostQuestion";
        string v = "@pt,@pq";

        lib.insert(t, f, v);
        lib.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pt", this.tbxTitle.Text);
        lib.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pq", this.tbxText.Text);


        lblshow.Text = "submited !!!";


    }
}
```

but when i play debug give me this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@pt".

from this code "lib.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()"
and this error in browser:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@pt".
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare
>   the scalar variable "@pt".
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 27:  Line 28:         lib.con.Open(); Line 29:
>   lib.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); Line 30:         lib.con.Close(); Line 31: 
>   }

how can i fix this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found answer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class ForumPost : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        string t = "TPost";
        string f = "PostTitle,PostQuestion";
        string v = "@pt,@pq";

        lib.insert(t, f, v);
        lib.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pt", this.tbxTitle.Text);
        lib.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pq", this.tbxText.Text);
        lib.con.Open();
        lib.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lib.con.Close();

        lblshow.Text = "submited !!!";


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var db = Database.open(/*your database*/);
string sqlcommand = "insert into TPost (PostTitle,PostQuestion,PostAnserw) values(@0,@1,@2)";
db.Execute(sqlcommand,param0,param1,param2);
```

There are also some security reasons to use @0,@1 like preventing sql injections.

Comment: in public static void insert

Comment: you should watch the videos on asp.net -> learn, then choose the asp you're using. Everything is explained in the videos and it makes it a lot easier